# null pointer point addView

Tags: android, view, android-fragments

Im trying to add a textview to a linear layout progmmatically, but I keep getting a null pointer on my linear layout. Its being called after the layout is inflated, so I do not understand why its happening. Heres the code.

tile_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:id="@+id/master"
android:orientation="horizontal"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
<TextView
android:id="@+id/fragment_two_directory"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Testing Fragment Two" />



</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_two.java

```
public class fragment_two extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tile_layout,container, false);
}

public static fragment_two newInstance(String directory, Activity activity) {
    fragment_two ft = new fragment_two();
    TextView text = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.fragment_two_directory);
    text.setText(directory);
    return ft;
}
public static void setDirectoryText(String directory, Activity activity) {
    TextView directoryText = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.fragment_two_directory);
    directoryText.setText(directory);
    populateDirectory(directory, activity);
}
public static void populateDirectory(String directory, Activity activity) {
    LinearLayout masterLinear = (LinearLayout)activity.findViewById(R.id.master);
    TextView testText = new TextView(activity);
    testText.setText("test");
    masterLinear.addView(testText);
    //testText.setText("Testing Add View");
    //for (int x=0; x < 5; x++) {
        //FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        //container.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //ImageView fileImage = new ImageView(getActivity());
        //fileImage.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(110, 110));
        //fileImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank_file);
        //container.addView(fileImage);
        //TextView fileName = new TextView(getActivity());
        //fileName.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //fileName.setText("Filename.txt");
        //container.addView(fileName);
        //masterLinear.addView(container);
    //}

}
}
```

And finally here is the main activity

```
package com.bv.dual_fragments;

import com.bv.dual_fragments.fragment_one.OnArticleSelectedListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class dual_fragments extends Activity implements OnArticleSelectedListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        //((global_holder)this.getApplication()).setDirectory("test"); 

    }
    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(String directory) {
        //fragment_two frag_two = (fragment_two)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        //TextView containerText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fragment_two_directory);
        //containerText.setText(directory);
        fragment_two.populateDirectory(directory, this);
    }
}
```

Heres the LogCat

```
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at     com.bv.dual_fragments.fragment_two.populateDirectory(fragment_two.java:36)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at com.bv.dual_fragments.dual_fragments.onArticleSelected(dual_fragments.java:25)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at com.bv.dual_fragments.fragment_one.onListItemClick(fragment_one.java:88)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:160)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:282)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1032)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2447)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3077)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3566)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:4600)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1488)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1256)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1700)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1270)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2271)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1680)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2272)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1958)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-06 17:35:47.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3576):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I also ran this in the honeycomb emulator, and looked at the heirarchy viewer. I have two linearlayout inside of that layoutfile, and neither of them are showing up, only the textview.

Comment: Post the entire traceback please.

Comment: Theres the logcat from DDMS, I think thats what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, that was.  Some of it, anyway.  It doesn't look complete.  I don't see the "Caused by" line.  Are you sure that's all of it?

Comment: HEres the other part, but this is it
03-06 17:35:36.332: WARN/ActivityManager(131): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{40ca9b98 com.bv.dual_fragments/.dual_fragments}
03-06 17:35:46.172: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3576): Shutting down VM
03-06 17:35:46.172: WARN/dalvikvm(3576): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40151760)

Comment: I probably need a different version of Eclipse, the debugger in this is horrible so far. Cant use breakpoints, cause I only get Local Source Not found errors, and the logcat doesnt really tell me anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the layout file was messed up and I had two linear layouts going horizontaly, and therefore the heirarchy wouldnt load them, giving the null point exception. Just a tip for anyone looking at the heirarchyviewer for Android 3.0, the fragment (inside the layoutfile) will automatically take ownership of the first layout tag in its inflated view. So say you have

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/viewer" />
```

and in your layout file you have

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/first_layout" />
```

In heirarchy viewer, the LinearLayout will appear as viewer, not first_layout, since the fragment doesnt have a default layout, its going to re-id the first layout container in its layoutfile to its own id.

Comment: How is this then overcome?

Answer (score 0):

Should you be setting the content view to `R.id.tile_layout` if you're trying to find `R.id.master`?

Right now you're looking for it in `test.xml`.

Comment: No, this is a fragmented layout, meaning different fragments call different layouts. the activty extends one layout, that actually holds the other layouts within it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that OnArticleSelected() is getting called after OnCreate()? findViewById(id) will return null if its called before the call setContentView(layout). Also try changing this line:

```
fragment_two.populateDirectory(directory, this);
```

to this:

```
fragment_two.populateDirectory(directory, dual_fragments.this);
```

If for some reason something other than an activity is getting passed in it will break things. I know you need to be distinct like this when making the call from inside an OnClickListener for a button, but Im not familiar with the listener you are using so I am not sure if it would be necessary. And Matthew brings a good point make sure you are pointing to the correct .xml file.

Comment: Yeah, its only called after I click on something in a different fragment. Ill try your change and see if that works.
It is the correct xml file. The activity uses test.xml, which holds the fragments. fragment_two uses tile_layout.xml as its layout.