# remove and add view NPE, honeycomb, android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-3.0-honeycomb, addition, android-gallery

I have `LinearLayout areaForGalleries` programmatically filled with `Gallery` components, one after another. `onItemClick` method in each gallery removes it from `areaForGalleries` and adds it to `RelativeLayout parentLayout` which is parent of `areaForGalleries`. See code below.

```
LinearLayout areaForGalleries;
RelativeLayout parentLayout;

...
private void showGallery() {
final CustomGallery mGallery = new CustomGallery(mContext);

mGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new CustomAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(CustomAdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            areaForGalleries.removeView(mGallery);
            parentLayout.addView(mGallery);
        }
    });
```

`CustomGallery` is my implementation of Android `Gallery` component. I've only changed alignment of the gallery to the left - one line of code has changed.
Code works perfectly on Android 2.1 - 2.3.3, but when tried it on Honeycomb or ICS it crashes with following error:

```
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:587)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at com.my.example.pullrefreshgallery.CustomGallery.onTouchEvent(CustomGallery.java:812)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5486)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1953)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1714)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1892)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at com.my.example.Home.dispatchTouchEvent(Home.java:883)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1840)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5662)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2863)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-31 10:31:49.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1536):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`NullPointerException` refers to `CustomGallery` method, which I haven't changed at all:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // Give everything to the gesture detector
    boolean retValue = mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // Helper method for lifted finger
        onUp();
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        onCancel();
    }

    return retValue;

}
```

When I comment out lines which removes and adds `mGallery` everything works perfectly!
There was [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5215553/1039411), but I'm not using fragments.

Any ideas what is wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I now it is not the answer you were waiting for but I just had the same problem only on ICS on the original Gallery widget (not overloaded).

After some test I fnally uses the easy way : try...catch

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    try {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The Galley is still working correctly and so is the onClickListener so there is no side effect for me.